# Derived Subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be an arbitrary group, and let $D$ denote its derived subgroup. I know that $D$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$, but is the following assertion true?

If $H$ is any subgroup of $G$ such that $D \cong H$, then $D = H.$

If the answer is negative, then a counterexample would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, I believe, with the following counterexample. If $G = D_{4} = \langle r, s \mid r^{4} = s^{2} = e, rs = sr^{-1} \rangle$, then the derived $D$ subgroup $G$ coincides with the center $Z(D_{4}) = \{e, r^{2}\}$. Hence, $D \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so any element of $G$ of order $2$ distinct from $r^{2}$ generates a cyclic subgroup $H$ with $H \cong D$ but $H \neq D$.

Comment: To be sure, there are elements of order $2$ distinct from $r^2$ in $D_4$, e.g., $r^ks$ for any integer $k$.